# Regular Expression not returning results

Tags: python, regex

I've written a regular expression and tested it in regex101.com, yet when I implement it in my code, I get no values returned and I have got no idea why.

I'm scraping a HTML document (an RSS feed specifically) and have got other regex's working with that HTML document within the same program, just not this particular one! I'm just at a loss since it works in regex101.com (and in another Python program I have access to which was developed specifically for testing regex's. I need to scrape the title of the article, the description and the date/time it was posted. Titles and date/time work (example of title working below) but I cannot get the description (variable 'snippets') to print.

**What I have tried:**

```
#There's a 'download' function earlier on which downloads the RSS page to a file
text_in = download(url='https://www.theverge.com/rss/index.xml', target_filename = 'downloadtheverge')
text_in = open('downloadtheverge.xhtml', 'r', encoding="utf8").read()

snippetresults = sorted
(set(findall(r'<p\sid=\"[A-Za-z0-9]*\">([A-Za-z0-9\s\-\—\:\/\,\’\'\‘\?\!\.]*\s?)<\/p>', text_in)))
for snippets in snippetresults:
    print(snippets)
```

**An example of what is being searched:**

`<p id="BjKuOh">Only a single key change isn’t being reversed: YouTube will actually verify that channels are authentic, whereas in the past it seemingly has not thoroughly taken this very obvious step.</p>`

**What is returned from the regex on regex101.com:**

'Only a single key change isn’t being reversed: YouTube will actually verify that channels are authentic, whereas in the past it seemingly has not thoroughly taken this very obvious step.'

**What does work:**

```
titlesresults = sorted
(set(findall(r'<title>([A-Za-z0-9\s\-\—\:\/\,\’\'\‘\?\!\.]+\s?)<\/title>', text_in)))
for titles in titlesresults:
    print(titles)
```

Same format, returns the titles in the HTML document to the shell window, like this:
'Beats headphones will get the same iOS 13.1 audio sharing feature as AirPods
Don’t update to iOS 13.0 if you play Fortnite or PUBG Mobile' etc etc

Yet when I run it in my program using the 'snippets', the shell window returns nothing... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the link to regex101 where you tested this?

Comment: `I'm scraping a HTML document` ... then you should be using the Beautiful Soup library, _not_ regex.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, I should add this is for a project where I can only use standard Python libraries...

Comment: The code that does not seem to work for you works for me (Python 3.7.4). Maybe you can show us how you are getting your `text_in`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 https://regex101.com/r/1XRz2D/1

Comment: Thanks @user10987432 I've updated the post to show the text_in code

Comment: With the example html you posted, the code works just fine (if I add `<title>` elements, since your example html doesn't actually contain the thing you're searching for). Please provide an example of both data and code that reproduces the error instead of having people guess at what you're doing.

Comment: What stands out about the html retrieved from the url provided, is that it has &lt; entities instead of '<' and other url-encoded text. Did you check for that?

Comment: Also, what is the `download` method?

Comment: @user10987432 fair question, although it's safe to assume it's some library method that downloads the document from the url and saves it in the file with the provided filename, which is loaded on the next line.

Comment: Thanks @Grismar, did you check out the regex link? Because the regular expression is valid, on regex101.com it picks up exactly what I need.

Comment: The regex is valid, but the text you're running it on is likely changing in transit - check the answer below.

Comment: @user10987432 It's just a function that opens the web page using urllib.request then reads it as a string using .read and then saves it locally using .write with parameters for filename, extension, etc.

Comment: @Grismar Just wasn't sure which standard python library has a `download` method with that signature. EDIT - Ah, gotcha.

Comment: @Grismar `What stands out about the html retrieved from the url provided, is that it has &lt; entities instead of '<' and other url-encoded text. Did you check for that?`
Good looking out and thanks for your below answer, this has solved the problem! Thanks for your help, I do really appreciate it!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
from re import findall
from urllib import request

text_in = request.urlopen(url='https://www.theverge.com/rss/index.xml').read().decode()

snippetresults = sorted(set(findall(r'<p\sid=\"[A-Za-z0-9]*\">([A-Za-z0-9\s\-\—\:\/\,\’\'\‘\?\!\.]*\s?)<\/p>', text_in)))
for snippets in snippetresults:
    print(snippets)
```

But this does (note the html entities):

```
from re import findall
from urllib import request

text_in = request.urlopen(url='https://www.theverge.com/rss/index.xml').read().decode()

snippetresults = sorted(set(findall(r'&lt;p\sid=\"[A-Za-z0-9]*\"&gt;([A-Za-z0-9\s\-\—\:\/\,\’\'\‘\?\!\.]*\s?)&lt;\/p&gt;', text_in)))
for snippets in snippetresults:
    print(snippets)
```

Comment: Cool. If the OP is super attached to having the regex look a certain way they can `html.escape` it.